# Xamarin (ios): Empty storyboard error message

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard

when I want to build my iphone app, I get an empty error message:
Base.lproj/AppStoryboard.storyboard: error :
The storyboard opens, but doesn't tell me where the error is.

What should I do to find out whats the problem is?

Comment: Task "IBTool" execution -- FAILED

Answer (score 0):

I found it out by myself. I had to set the deployment target to version 9.1 from 7.1 I had. :/

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else meet this kind of error there is simple way to checkout what exactly wrong.

1. Go to Build Output
2. Find `Task "IBTool" execution -- FAILED` line
3. One or two line above there is string like `Tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool execution started with arguments: --errors --warnings --notices` etc. Copy everything after `:` including path to your xib or storyboard
4. Open Terminal app, write `ibtool`, paste all arguments you copied and run command.
5. Few seconds later you'll got plist xml with errors and warnings you can discover and fix.